# How to make a steady button irrespective to screen size

Tags: android, android-view, android-button

How to make the app Button steady in it's place and doesn't move or change place by the device screen size in android studio?

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:text="START ENGINE"
    android:id="@+id/play"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:layout_marginLeft="88dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="88dp"
    android:background="#ffb55b19"
    android:onClick="startup"
    android:layout_marginBottom="198dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right|top|center|bottom"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

Comment: Depends on what other assets you have on the screen. Also what layout type you are using. I.E. relative, Linear, etc.

Comment: i am using relative layout over linear layout, when i change from portrait mode to landscape in the emulator the place of button changes,so what can i do to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

there are options available for centering in both the verticle as well as the horizontal when it comes to relative layout. like this.

```
     <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Comment: I think just get rid off all the align nonsense and margin nonsense and do the layout_center.